# There is no Cell Broadcast option in HTC Desire C

Tags: settings, cell-broadcast

I get annoying messages, like every 2 minutes, saying my location. I can't turn it off. I searched all settings and options, but CB option is nowhere to find.

Is something wrong with my Android version or what?